# Can an unemployed person get a UK Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

I am currently unemployed and is helping on my family's business.They give me money but not monthly and when they give it is in bulk( like for instance they will give me a big money that is worth for months of work) I do save it on my bank account but I don't do it on a  monthly basis cause of busy schedule.

What proof should I show when applying for a UK Visa?

Comment: I am sure it depends on which type of visa you want to apply for...

Comment: I am applying for a tourist visa btw

Comment: This is just a guess but I expect they'd be rather suspicious of somebody who says that they're unemployed, but working and being paid, and being paid in such an irregular way.

Comment: If you are working in the family business and they give you money for that, you are employed. Payment doesn't have to be regular to be employed. Take your bank account statement.

Comment: @juan Jimenez So is it okay to not have a pay slip and a vacation leave form or something? I just click in "assistant manager" since I help my brother manage our business.But how can I support my answer to the embassy? Please help.

Comment: Have your brother (or whomever owns the business) write a letter in company letterhead stating that you are the assistant manager.

Comment: A letter from your family business explaining the situation (also that you will not be working for them while in  the UK) would help.

Comment: @juanJimenez Hi Juan, regarding about my situation.Our family business is owned and named after my Dad who just passed away this year.We are still currently processing the papers in order for it to be transferred to our names (me,mom and my other sibs). I claimed in this post that im "unemployed" because I do not have Income tax return or employment cert (we do not have an HR office) but I do work and manage our fanily business (small resort) ever since my dad pass away.

Comment: @JuanJimenez My question is is it enough to show my bank statement that I can support myself on this trip andy father's death cert to support  my ties on our family business and that I do not have any intention to stay longer in the UK.Please help.

Comment: I cannot answer that.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Hi mark,can you help me with my situation if you have any idea? Sadly Juan can't answer it.It's before this message